# Changing text color based on page position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my site, I have a sticky navbar that is always positioned at the top of my site, so even as you scroll down, it's still visible.

It's also transparent, and just contains some black text.

The problem is that on my page, there are several divs with varying background colors. So as I scroll down the page, the text in the nav looks fine as I overlay divs with lighter backgrounds, but it's really hard to read on darker ones.

I figure I have two options:

1. Change the nav text color based on if I'm overlaying a div with class "dark"
2. Change the nav text color based on the background color of the div beneath it.

Are either of these possible? Or is there another option I'm not aware of?

Comment: The sticky navbar doesn't have a background? I'd say it should have one and your problem goes away.

Comment: Just google [Jquery collision detection](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=jquery%20collision%20detection) and maybe you can adapt one of the many results

Answer (score 0):

I just read about [Midnight.js](http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/), a jQuery plugin that allows you to use data-attributes on the elements you scroll over to define how your navigation should look. Might be worth to give it a look.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery Waypoints.  It's perfect for your problem.  You can specify exact waypoints so that the moment a differently colored div hits your menubar, an event is fired.  and in that event you can change the menubar color.  And then you'd have another waypoint at the bottom of that div so you could reset the color.

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/